# Alarm initiated automatically at first time set a alarm

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, alarm

I am using alarm to start service at every 15 days once. Alarm is initiated at the first time of installation. Every 15 days once alarm trigger that service properly, but At the time of initiating alarm the service started.I dont want to start the service at the time of installation. how to stop this.
I dont whether i am using wrong format?

> Note: Apart from this condition, I am not start service anywhere.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, InitiateService.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 12345, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 15 * AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);
```

> this what i used in manifest file.

```
 <service android:name=".service.InitiateService" />
```

this is my code of initiating alarm for starting service at every 15days once.

> Guys If any one found any wrong in my question, Apologies me and Please correct those mistakes and answer me.

Comment: post your code for further investigation

Comment: @Ahamed thanks for your response dude. I already post my code. wheather it is not enough?

Answer (score 1):

it is because you used **System.currentTimeMillis()**

try this

**System.currentTimeMillis()*(15 * AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY)**

```
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()*(15 * AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY), 15 * AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer dude, i will try and let you know

Comment: Sorry dude. Its not working. Again its initiated immediatelly.

Comment: ok but, it should work problem is there at System.currentTimeMillis() because you are triggering alarm at Current Time

Comment: Hello, you could try to add a calendar.        Calendar calendar =    Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY, 15);

    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                15 * AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);

Comment: @FranckKallaway thanks for your answer. its working fine but after 15days if i restart the device the service is not triggered for 15 days count but after 15days that alarm trigger that service properly. I put one BroadcastReceiver for initiate alarm after Boot Completed. in there i am using the same code.

Comment: Do you think about something like a persistent storage for your alarm wake up? (boot proof and app relaunch proof?)

Answer (score 1):

@Mehul Gajjar is correct about `System.currentTimeMillis()`

so you might wanna replace

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

with

```
(15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * System.currentTimeMillis())
```

**Explanation :**

`System.currentTimeMillis()` will set Alarm to current time, so your service will start straight away. setting Alarm after 15 days will solve your problem.
`15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` will be equals to 15 days. multiplying it with current time-miles will give you current time after 15 days.

in-short your code would be like

```
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * System.currentTimeMillis()), 15 * AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for your answer dude. I will check once again and let you know.

Comment: sorry dude, still it is initiated again at first time.

Comment: can you please show me how you are initialising your service?

Comment: @ V-rund Puro-hit, i already mention in quetion, that how i triggering service using alarammanager